# Access Component Attributes in Directive Vue

Tags: vue.js, components, directive

I have created a directive that is used in the component.

```
const disableSelectIfOneItem = {
  inserted: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    //want to access component attribute here
  }
}

<v-autocomplete
                      v-model="fieldData.account"
                      :items="accountOptions"
                      item-text="name"
                      item-value="id"
                      dense
                      clearable
                      outlined
                      :disabled="disabledAccountSelect"
                      filled
                      :label="$t('Account')"
                      hide-details="auto"
                      v-disable-select
                  ></v-autocomplete>
```

How can I access a component attribute from directives like "label".

Answer (score 0):

When you use **Vue-js**, you can benefit from **Data** that is built in vue components. For example suppose that you have a component that is called **input-compo** and the code of it is like below:

> input-compo.vue :

```html
<template>
  <input type="text">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "inputCompo",
  props: ['label']
}
</script>

<style scoped>
input {
  margin: 53px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

Suppose that we want to use this component in a parent component and use **v-disable-select-if-one-item** custom directive on that like below:

> parent component:

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <div>
      <input-compo v-disable-select-if-one-item="textData" :label="textData"></input-compo>
    </div>

  </section>
</template>

<script>

import inputCompo from "../components/inputCompo";
export default {
  name: "About",
  data() {
    return {
      /* If you want to access single attribute value inside your directive use an simple text data. */
      textData: "some-text",
      /* If you want to access multiple attributes value inside your directive use an object. */
      objecData: {
        label: "some-text",
        itemValue: "text2"
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    inputCompo
  },

  directives: {
    disableSelectIfOneItem:  {
      inserted: function (el, binding) {
      /* you can access the value passed in directive with the help of "binding.value"  */
        console.log(binding.value);
        el.focus()
      }
    }
  },

}
</script>
```

In this way if you change "textData" in your component, both `label` prop and `v-disable-select-if-one-item` custom directive values changes accordingly.

Comment: What if i want to modified 'textData' in directives and also parent component 'textData' also change?

Comment: According to [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments) : Apart from ```el```, you should treat these arguments as **read-only** and never **modify** them. If you need to share information across hooks, it is recommended to do so through element’s dataset.